# Android adding text to textview dynamically in Fragment (wrap_content)

Tags: android, android-fragments, height, android-wrap-content

I have a problem with adding text to TextView which is placed in horizontal LinearLayout in Fragment. After adding some text the view always shows only 1 line. TextView height is  not wrapping to its content.

My xml file:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="28"
            style="@style/Theme.Material"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black_blue"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="24"
            style="@style/Theme.Material"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt1Value"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black_blue"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="24"
            style="@style/Theme.Material"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt2Value"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black_blue"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp" />
        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="24"
            style="@style/Theme.Material"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt3Value"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/black_blue"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingRight="1dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I would appreciate any ideas how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
  TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.txt);
  String YOUR_TEXT = "Your text \n text \n text" 
  tv.setText(YOUR_TEXT + "\n" + "text text text")
```

than inside of the TextView there are will be as many lines as you put **"\n"**.

Comment: Thats not about it. My text is adding properly. But the height of text view in fragment layout only shows the 1 line.

Comment: Than probably there is something wrong with style="@style/Theme.Material"

Comment: I dont think so cause everywhere is working fine and when i put some text in xml to Textview it is showing on the fragment view (height is adjusting to  multilines). I think the problem is with the thing that fragment view is refreshing height is adjusting before text is changing